# Vue 2 -> 3 migration: vite reloads app after random navigations

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-router, vite

I am migrating Vue 2 to 3 and one problem I am currently encountering is that after some navigations the app gets reloaded by vite. Is this expected behaviour? I am not sure if this is related to the errors which I still have in the app (some vuetify components are missing in v3 for example), caused by a memory leak and an overflow which is reached at some point. Or whether this is from a misconfigured router.

Comment: Certainly not _all_ Vue 3 apps reload after navigation, but no one can truly say whether it's expected or not of _your_ app without any code to review. I would at least resolve any other known errors before focusing on it since you never know what kind of side-effects are being produced by said errors.